# Screenshotting other windows from web browser

Tags: image, google-chrome, web, screenshot

I would like to create a web application that allows users to screenshot an external application window, then do some processing on the image. The specific context - I would like the app to screenshot a video game loading screen, then load useful pregame information to give players a strategic synopsis of the upcoming game while it's loading. However I want the app to run from a browser, but the game is an external windows application. I know how to do the image processing, and information loading once the image is imported to the web app, but don't know the best way to grab the screenshot easily. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is possible due to security risks involved in being able to capture screenshots of applications outside of Google Chrome, for example private documents, emails, etcetera.

The closest thing that exists is the `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`, but that only allows for you to capture the current tab's screenshot.